# Custom SectionHeaderView with CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I've problems with my custom sectionHeaderView. I'm getting the following error:

> **error:** Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the
>   delegate of `NSFetchedResultsController` during a call to
>   `-controllerDidChangeContent:`.
>
> Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after
>   the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in
>   the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of
>   sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo
>   (null)

If I use the normal `titleForHeaderInSection`, everything's working fine.

Changing to `viewForHeaderInSection` causes the error. That's the code for viewForHeaderinSection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let currSection = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else { return nil }
    let headerView = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: ContractListHeaderView.reuseIdentifier) as! ContractListHeaderView
    print(currSection.name)
    headerView.sectionLabel.text = currSection.name
    return headerView
}
```

And that's my `fetchedResultsController`:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        guard let newIndexPath = newIndexPath else { return }
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    case .delete:
        guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    case .update:
        guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    case .move:
        guard let indexPath = indexPath, let newIndexPath = newIndexPath else { return }
        if indexPath == newIndexPath {
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
        }
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you implement [`controllerWillChangeContent(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate/1622295-controllerwillchangecontent)/[`controllerDidChangeContent(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate/1622290-controllerdidchangecontent)?

Comment: Yes, with tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates()